# Config Builder Not Finding Environment Variable

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, visual-studio, asp-net-config-builders

When I view the connection string while debugging, the value is "abc"; not what I've set the Windows environment variable to.

### web.config

```
<configSections>
  <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<configBuilders>
   <builders>
      <add name="Environment" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
   </builders>
</configBuilders>

<connectionStrings configBuilders="Environment">
   <add name="myConnection" connectionString="abc" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/
</connectionStrings>
```

I've double checked that the correct Nuget packages are installed, that the framework is correctly on 4.7.2, that my spelling is correct, and I've read the Microsoft docs on [Configuration Builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/config-builder) several times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Microsoft document linked above, [Configuration builders for ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/config-builder), there exists the following footnote:

> Note: You might need to exit and restart Visual Studio to see changes in environment variables.

That fixed it.

Comment: Oh my. I was messing about with this for FAR too long. Glad I saw this answer though.